# Scala if condition for string gives different result

Tags: scala

vc100_60 is greater than vc75_60

How do I achieve it in scala code

```
 scala> val str1 ="vc100_60"
 str1: String = vc100_60

 scala> val str2 ="vc75_60"
 str2: String = vc75_60

 scala> val result = if(str1 > str2) { println(str1) } else {println(str2)}
 vc75_60
```

Expected answer is vc100_60
but I get vc75_60

What code change needs to be done to get vc100_60 from the if condition

Comment: Strings are compared lexicographically, so `vc100_60` < `vc75_60` because `1` < `7`; Do you mean you know the input _format_ and would like to only compare the part between `vc` and `_` numerically?

Comment: yes, I think I need to apply split and substring and cast to int and the compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can parse these strings into the Integer values you're interested in for comparison - here's one using a Regular Expression:

```
val regex = """vc(\d+)_.*""".r

def parse(str: String): Int = str match {
  case regex(v) => v.toInt
  case _ => 0 // when parsing fails; Alternatively - throw exception or use a different default value
}

if (parse(str1) > parse(str2)) { println(str1) } else { println(str2) }

// or, another way to print the minimum 
// which can easily be applied to more than two strings:
val min = List(str1, str2).minBy(parse)
println(min)
```

Of course I made some assumptions about the format based on the two examples, fix the regex if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lexicographic comparison. They are compared position wise. In this case `"99"` will be greater than `"1000"` because first character is greater in `"99"`. Whenever one character becomes great, others are not compared.